# Error when extending class

Tags: java, extend

I'm pretty new to Java, so I don't know what's going wrong. What I have here is a code that is, when it's executed, supposed to "open" a window once, but whenever I extend the class `ColoredWordsExperiment` in the `ButtonHandler` class, the window opens infinitely really quickly which nearly causes my computer to crash everytime. If I leave out the extension then it works fine, but then I won't be able to use the objects from the `ColoredWordsExperiment` class in the `ButtonHandler` class... Below you can find the code (I left some unimportant stuff out otherwise it'd become too long).

```
public class ColoredWordsExperiment {
    JFrame frame;
    ButtonHandler buttonHandler;

ColoredWordsExperiment(){
    frame = new JFrame("Colored Words Experiment");
    frame.setSize(1200, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button1 = new JButton("Matching");

    label1 = new JLabel("test");
    label1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 40));

    JPanel labelContainer = new JPanel();
    labelContainer.add(label1);

    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    buttonContainer.add(button1);

    frame.add(buttonContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(labelContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    button1.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
}

public static void main(String[] arg) {
     new ColoredWordsExperiment();
}

}
```

-

```
public class ButtonHandler extends ColoredWordsExperiment implements ActionListener {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Matching")) {
        System.out.println("Matching");
        label1.setText("Text changed");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to extend `ColoredWordsExperiment` in this case. You should simply be implementing `ActionListener`.

You're essentially initializing another instance of `ColoredWordsExperiment` inside itself with a single additional method. This causes your constructor be called again, which causes the GUI window to be recreated.
See [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more details.

If you want to change a field in `ColoredWordsExperiment` from your `ActionListener` implementation, you'll want to pass a reference during construction.

```
public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    ColoredWordsExperiment coloredWords;
    public ButtonHandler(ColoredWordsExperiment coloredWords) {
        this.coloredWords = coloredWords;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Matching")) {
            System.out.println("Matching");
            coloredWords.label1.setText("Text changed");
        }
    }
}
```

---

In this case, you also have the option of creating an anonymous inner class. With this technique, you can completely get rid of the `ButtonHandler` class.
Inside `ColoredWordsExperiment` instead of

```
buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
button1.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
```

You can use

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Matching")) {
        System.out.println("Matching");
        label1.setText("Text changed");
    }
});
```

See [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: You should explain to him why the code acts that way

Comment: Ok but I want to change the text of label1 whenever the "Matching" button is clicked, how would I do that without extending ColoredWordsExperiment in ButtonHandler? Since label1.setText("Text changed"); doesn't work if I don't extend ColoredWordsExperiment.

Comment: Edited to add more details, along with an explanation of anonymous inner classes. Both solutions should take care of that.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the first method as I don't understand the second (which actually looks easier but well). I still got a question though, If I use the first method, what should I pass as argument in "buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler(what to put here);" in the ColoredWordsExperiment class?

Comment: You'll be passing a reference of the `ColoredWordsExperiment` instance into the constructor. So use
    
    buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler(this);

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the parent class, you are creating one of those ButtonHandlers wich, in turn, runs the constructor code again.
You should not instantiate this class in the constructor (or use a different name for it if you are attempting to use one with the same name)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i can see what tour problem is. Now i don't know why you want to extend it, I'm just trying to answer your question (b/c there is no need to extend an action listener to your main class). when you define the class method you didn't put a public, and then when you put under the main method to run it, it could be confused and make infinite frames. You should change it to this:

```
public class ColoredWordsExperiment {
    JFrame frame;
    ButtonHandler buttonHandler;

   public ColoredWordsExperiment(){//add the public!
    frame = new JFrame("Colored Words Experiment");
    frame.setSize(1200, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button1 = new JButton("Matching");

    label1 = new JLabel("test");
    label1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 40));

    JPanel labelContainer = new JPanel();
    labelContainer.add(label1);

    JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
    buttonContainer.add(button1);

    frame.add(buttonContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(labelContainer, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    buttonHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    button1.addActionListener(buttonHandler);
   }

   public static void main(String[] arg) {
       new ColoredWordsExperiment();
    }

}
```

Additionally, it's not a good idea to define your `buttonHandler` variable as your ButtonHandler class in your Main class but then have your ButtonHandler class extend off your Main class. that could cause a loop. you should either not extend your second class or define your `buttonHandler` variable in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to read up and understand the difference between **classes** and **objects**. To help you with that I want to illustrate a problem with the way you were originally thinking about your code with a simplified example:

```
class A {
    int x;
    B b = new B();
}

class B extends A {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        a.x = 42;
        a.b.x = 53;

        System.out.println(a.x);
        System.out.println(a.b.x);
    }
}
```

As expected, the object `a` in `main()` has a field named `x` and we can set it to 42. However, the object `b` inside of `a` has **its own** field named `x` which is **completely unrelated** to the field `x` inside of the object `a`.

If you can get your head around the concept of objects, you will be well on your way to becoming a good Java programmer.